# Instalar Módulo openalpr

Tags: python

Boa noite desenvolvedores.
Eu estou precisando baixar um módulo para Python, porém eu não estou conseguindo, procurei na internet e principalmente no StackOverflow em inglês, porém de nada adiantou, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei agradecido.

Edit:
Desde ontem eu estava tentando instalar o módulo no notebook, eu tentei instalar via pip, e pegando o package do Git, extrai o arquivo, abri o CMD e fui e instalei corretamente, porém quando eu ia executar o arquivo dava problema de módulo não encontrado, então eu fui tentar novamente agora pouco e o módulo passou , porém outros erros foram encontrados, estarei deixando imagens

Clique em Executar para ver algumas imagens:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="MdQcTwd"><a href="//imgur.com/MdQcTwd">View post on imgur.com</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="udwI9Ap"><a href="//imgur.com/udwI9Ap">View post on imgur.com</a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit2:
A pedido de **@Sidon** código dos erros:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\openalpr\openalpr.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._openalprpy_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libopenalprpy.dll")
  File "C:\Users\Andreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Andreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andreza\Desktop\asdasd.py", line 3, in <module>
    alpr = Alpr("us", "/path/to/openalpr.conf", "/path/to/runtime_data")
  File "C:\Users\Andreza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\openalpr\openalpr.py", line 58, in __init__
    raise nex
OSError: Unable to locate the OpenALPR library. Please make sure that OpenALPR is properly installed on your system and that the libraries are in the appropriate paths.
```

Módulo: openalpr

Comment: Não é isso? https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/src/bindings/python

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss - Afirmativo, porém estou com problemas para executar

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta e adicione todas essas informações. Coloque todos os passos que você fez e qual é o erro retornado. Da maneira que está, sua pergunta está carente de detalhes e pode ser fechada por não estar clara.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tudo bem

Answer (score 1):

O Openalpr em si é um pacote binário desenvolvido em C (e outras linguagens) e, opcionalmente, um webservice. Esse pacote faz binding com várias linguagens, entre elas o python.

**Att.: Exemplos nessa resposta estão baseados no Linux (Debian).**

A [documentação](http://doc.openalpr.com/index.html) diz que existem 2 maneiras de vc fazer integração do OpenALPR com a sua aplicação:

- Usar o DFK comercial para compilar as bibliotecas do OpenALPR dentro
  da sua aplicação e processar frames de imagens individualmente;
- Rodar o executável OpenALPR Agent para capturar diretamente os feeds
  de vídeo e enviar os resultados das placas e imagens para o seu
  aplicativo.

> Comercial SDK

Windows, baixe-o aqui: 
 
http://deb.openalpr.com/windows-sdk/openalpr64-sdk-latest.zip

Linux:

```
bash <(curl http://deb.openalpr.com/install)
```

**Fazendo o bind no SDK:**

Faça o clone do repositorio:

```
git clone https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr.git
```

Instalação:

```
cd openalpr/src/bindings/python/
python setup.py install
```

utilização

```
from openalpr import Alpr

alpr = Alpr("us", "/path/to/openalpr.conf", "/path/to/runtime_data")
if not alpr.is_loaded():
    print("Error loading OpenALPR")
    sys.exit(1)

alpr.set_top_n(20)
alpr.set_default_region("md")

results = alpr.recognize_file("/path/to/image.jpg")

i = 0
for plate in results['results']:
    i += 1
    print("Plate #%d" % i)
    print("   %12s %12s" % ("Plate", "Confidence"))
    for candidate in plate['candidates']:
        prefix = "-"
        if candidate['matches_template']:
            prefix = "*"

        print("  %s %12s%12f" % (prefix, candidate['plate'], candidate['confidence']))

# Call when completely done to release memory
alpr.unload()
```

> Webserver

Uma segunda opção é utiliza-lo como web-server, nesse caso a [documentação](http://doc.openalpr.com/index.html) recomenda a utilização do ubuntu 16.04, para que possa rodar o web-server, se for essa opção melhor estudar a documentação e, de qualquer forma, vc tera que usar parte da terceira opção, em seguida.

> CloudAPI

A terceira opcao talvez seja a mais "fácil", é a utilização da API "nas nuvens" dos caras:

[The OpenALPR Cloud API is a service running in the cloud that is ready to analyze your images. The service receives image data and responds with license plate information, as well as vehicle color, make, and model.](http://www.openalpr.com/cloud-api.html)

Para essa opção, assine o serviço (Grátis para 2.000 reconhecimentos/mes ), instale a api python e [leia a documentação](http://doc.openalpr.com/index.html).

Baixe a cloudapi

```
git clone https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi.git
```

Instale no python

```
cd cloudapi/python
pip install -r requirements.txt
sudo python setup.py install
```

Para utilizar

```
>>> import openalpr_api
```

**REFERENCIA**
 
[Documentação oficial](http://doc.openalpr.com/index.html)

Comment: Eu já havia feito estes procedimentos, aparentemente o módulo foi instalado corretamente via CMD, porém quando vou executar o código apresentado, o mesmo retorna erro no módulo, como se ele não estive instalado no computador, porém eu já o instalei diversas vezes.

Comment: Qual das opcoes? Agent, Webservice? Cloud? Qual seru sistema operacional?

Comment: Eu utilizei o método de instalar pelo CMD, baixando o package e instalar via CMD com o python install.

Windows 8 64bits

Comment: Da para vc reproduzir aqui o codigo que vc esta tentando rodar e os erros que estão ocorrendo? Edit a pergunta e acrescente essas informações.

Comment: Editei e acrescentei os código de erro

Comment: Veja a ultima mensagem:

OSError: Unable to locate the OpenALPR library. Please make sure that OpenALPR is properly installed on your system and that the libraries are in the appropriate paths.

A mensagem diz que a biblioteca nao esta instalada. Se tiver não esta no path. Eu pedi para voce colocar o codigo tambem, da para fazer isso?

Comment: Como pode ver nesta imagem http://imgur.com/MdQcTwd o módulo foi instalado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56890/discussion-between-felix-and-sidon).

Comment: Movi os comentários para o chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56890/discussion-between-felix-and-sidon